# h:commandButton action is not getting called inside primefaces p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem in my jsf application. I am calling action method by using `h:commandButton` inside `p:dialog` but it is not getting called. If i put `p:dialog` 
outside `h:form` in which it was enclosed and put everything enclosed inside `h:form` in `p:dialog`, still it is not working. If i put button outside `p:dialog` it is 
working fine.

any help regarding this is very useful for me. Advanced thanks......

---

**@maple_shaft**  I have put appendToBody="true" but still it is not working.

**@Daniel**  I have placed p:dialog outside main form and placed everything inside dialog in another form but it is not working-----i am using log4j for checking weather a method is getting called or not, here it is not printing anything.   If i place the command button outside p:dialog it is working perfectly.

Comment: make sure you don't place form inside form , place the dialog outside your main form and place another form inside your dialog... b.t.w do you see any errors in firebug / web server ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show your xhtml code. Also, take the recommendations from Daniel

Comment: Did you try adding `appendToBody="true"` attribute on the dialog?

Comment: My Problem is solved.... The problem is with disabled option of p:commandButton.Earlier i was getting value of a bean variable and comparing it like this  **<p:commandButton disabled="#{adminbean.boot != 'ON'}"/>**, and this was not working. Now instead of comparing it on client side i am comparing it on server side and returning a boolean value, and based on this value i am disabling/enabling the button. But i don't know how this is working? What is the problem with the first approach... Anyway thanks for your co-operation.